# How to Read RSS and Show Posts in github Page

Tags: rss, jekyll

Is there any way to add show RSS Posts from a link in a Github Pages.

I want to read RSS Feed from any website and show the feed in form of post in single page or a control with multiple page using jekyll

Comment: A starting point here https://rubygems.org/gems/jekyll-planet.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show that to us?

Answer (score 1):

Without using plugins you can load the XML on a page and simulate pageloads with javascript. Here is an example of a Jekyll website doing just that: https://amber-gnu.cloudvent.net/subsidies/subsidiewijzer/.

If you to convert the RSS into real entries/.md files in your repository, you should look for a plugin.